# 127.0.0.2 address ping reply is coming from 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11

I have no idea what has happend in my windows configuration. But when i ping address `127.0.0.2` address reply is coming from `127.0.0.1`.
This was not like this before and this is important to me as this cause my test suit to fail, as i use some software simulators, that use ping to check if machine is available but they check if reply ip address is the same we send ping to. Is this somehow configurable in windows or maybe they messed something in latest windows 11 update

Comment: Where is 127.0.0.2 supposed to be?

Comment: 127.0.0.0/8 addresses are reserved for loopback, they're handled by the OS, and AFAIK these can't be configured. I wouldn't be using these addresses in any simulated machines or VMs.

Comment: @Tetsujin it is nothing, software simulator that i use for tests. Before it was working fine, i mean it was working fine for perhaps 10 years or more. Asked other ppl and it is still working fine for them.